# Error in echo JSON object in foreach PHP

Tags: php, foreach, jsondecoder

Why does not this code output correct? I used this code in many scripts but I receive the following error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Users\TPA-LAPTOP\AppData\Local\Temp\prev3~.php on line 7
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Users\TPA-LAPTOP\AppData\Local\Temp\prev3~.php on line 7
> PHP Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Users\TPA-LAPTOP\AppData\Local\Temp\prev3~.php on line 7 PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Users\TPA-LAPTOP\AppData\Local\Temp\prev3~.php on line 7

```
<?php
$data = '{ "geocoded_waypoints" : [ { "geocoder_status" : "OK", "place_id" : "ChIJZ6jEM5S_7D8R2fAwJ8YlcZ8", "types" : [ "route" ] }, { "geocoder_status" : "OK", "place_id" : "ChIJg8uWnlMAjj8R1tzKih3Lzzc", "types" : [ "route" ] } ], "routes" : [ { "bounds" : { "northeast" : { "lat" : 35.6839107, "lng" : 51.38573599999999 }, "southwest" : { "lat" : 34.0713368, "lng" : 49.7157596 } }, "copyrights" : "Map data ©2018 Google", "legs" : [ { "distance" : { "text" : "279 km", "value" : 279413 }, "duration" : { "text" : "3 hours 7 mins", "value" : 11204 }, "end_address" : "Tehran Province, Tehran, 7th Street, Iran", "end_location" : { "lat" : 35.6825616, "lng" : 51.38573599999999 }, "start_address" : "Markazi Province, Arak, Qods Boulevard, Iran", "start_location" : { "lat" : 34.094294, "lng" : 49.7157596 }, "steps" : [ { "distance" : { "text" : "0.9 km", "value" : 947 }, "duration" : { "text" : "1 min", "value" : 89 }, "end_location" : { "lat" : 34.0988852, "lng" : 49.72428799999999 }, "html_instructions" : "Head \u003cb\u003enortheast\u003c/b\u003e on \u003cb\u003eQods Blvd\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eEmam Hoseyn\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003ePass by موسسه‌ خدمات حفاظتی و مراقبتی نظم گستر صدرا (on the left)\u003c/div\u003e", "polyline" : { "points" : "i`boEobmnH]cAi@}AGQ_@cAyAiEg@mAQg@EKcAqCs@uBa@aBK]kAaD[{@aB}DKUKQMQOSe@g@cA}@k@i@UWUWW[MW" }, "start_location" : { "lat" : 34.094294, "lng" : 49.7157596 }, "travel_mode" : "DRIVING" }, { "distance" : { "text" : "80 m", "value" : 80 }, "duration" : { "text" : "1 min", "value" : 13 }, "end_location" : { "lat" : 34.0988768, "lng" : 49.7237912 }, "html_instructions" : "Make a \u003cb\u003eU-turn\u003c/b\u003e", "maneuver" : "uturn-left", "polyline" : { "points" : "a}boEywnnHEAMCE?E@EBCFAD?F@JBL@HDJ^\\" }, "start_location" : { "lat" : 34.0988852, "lng" : 49.72428799999999 }, "travel_mode" : "DRIVING" }, { "distance" : { "text" : "0.4 km", "value" : 358 }, "duration" : { "text" : "1 min", "value" : 31 }, "end_location" : { "lat" : 34.1010534, "lng" : 49.7212189 }, "html_instructions" : "Slight \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003e‫‫بزرگراه شهید آنجفی‬‬‎\u003c/b\u003e", "maneuver" : "turn-slight-right", "polyline" : { "points" : "_}boEutnnHJ`@BPCNGNS\\UXc@b@eAx@cDjCwApAe@x@" }, "start_location" : { "lat" : 34.0988768, "lng" : 49.7237912 }, "travel_mode" : "DRIVING" }, { "distance" : { "text" : "0.4 km", "value" : 406 }, "duration" : { "text" : "1 min", "value" : 21 }, "end_location" : { "lat" : 34.1040261, "lng" : 49.7186615 }, "html_instructions" : "Slight \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003e‫‫بزرگراه شهید آنجفی‬‬‎\u003c/b\u003e", "maneuver" : "turn-slight-right", "polyline" : { "points" : "qjcoEsdnnHoDlCcCrB_H|F" }, "start_location" : { "lat" : 34.1010534, "lng" : 49.7212189 }, "travel_mode" : "DRIVING" }, { "distance" : { "text" : "0.5 km", "value" : 520 }, "duration" : { "text" : "1 min", "value" : 48 }, "end_location" : { "lat" : 34.1083846, "lng" : 49.7194473 }, "html_instructions" : "Slight \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e", "maneuver" : "turn-slight-right", "polyline" : { "points" : "e}coEstmnHG?I?I@s@`@GFIBKBKBK?e@AoDMsCG_@G{@EsAIWEWEIEGEGCEGMMKO_AwAGEKAGC" }, "start_location" : { "lat" : 34.1040261, "lng" : 49.7186615 }, "travel_mode" : "DRIVING" }, { "distance" : { "text" : "1.8 km", "value" : 1776 }, "duration" : { "text" : "2 mins", "value" : 138 }, "end_location" : { "lat" : 34.1172737, "lng" : 49.7350356 }, "html_instructions" : "Slight \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003eBolvar Keshavarz\u003c/b\u003e", "maneuver" : "turn-slight-right", "polyline" : { "points" : "kxdoEqymnHkA_CuByDS]qAeCoA_CeB_DSc@iCiFwBiEmEeIkEuGaCkEKQwDgH]m@]q@Wi@_@w@q@{Ae@iAk@mAk@kBCK[qAGYJMLUHUFW@I" }, "start_location" : { "lat" : 34.1083846, "lng" : 49.7194473 }, "travel_mode" : "DRIVING" }, { "distance" : { "text" : "6.2 km", "value" : 6236 }, "duration" : { "text" : "5 mins", "value" : 317 }, "end_location" : { "lat" : 34.072538, "lng" : 49.7755983 }, "html_instructions" : "Slight \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003eNorthern Hwy (Imam Ali Hwy)\u003c/b\u003e/\u003cb\u003eRoute 47\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003ePass by Central Province Police Headquarters (on the right in 3.6 km)\u003c/div\u003e", "maneuver" : "turn-slight-right", "polyline" : { "points" : "}ofoE_{pnHZ_@jCaCbEqDjLsKdGgFrRcQbLkKlAiAd@c@hEsDxGeGjEuDl@c@d@]lAoAr@u@v@s@h@i@rEgEjDwCBCxGcGdA}@f@e@FGlD_DlBcBLKhI}HzI{HFGlKcJbDoCtCkCfD_DbFmEjBaBzBmBxEgEdEwDvCiCdD{CtCkCnBkBx@u@|@w@zBkBxGgGxGcGt@o@bHkG|BuBnCgC^SVITC@?^?f@AT@TG" }, "start_location" : { "lat" : 34.1172737, "lng" : 49.7350356 }, "travel_mode" : "DRIVING" }, { "distance" : { "text" : "132 km", "value" : 132287 }, "duration" : { "text" : "1 hour 25 mins", "value" : 5120 }, "end_location" : { "lat" : 34.6782574, "lng" : 50.8941868 }, "html_instructions" : "At \u003cb\u003eImam Khomeini Square\u003c/b\u003e, take the \u003cb\u003e4th\u003c/b\u003e exit onto \u003cb\u003eRoute 56\u003c/b\u003e/\u003cb\u003eAH8\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003eContinue to follow Route 56\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003ePass by سامان صنعت مرکزی (on the right in 600 m)\u003c/div\u003e", "maneuver" : "roundabout-right", "polyline" : { "points" : "kx}nEoxxnHDDFJ@?JJFDF@D@D@F?R?J?RATCLEHCLIJKLMRWPYNe@^oABKV_AFq@F[BQ@SIo@Oo@IQMUQOGGMEQE[u@W]Q[I[Me@I}@IaCI{Cc@_HkDmk@wAyVcAwPm@{JiAuRaCu`@iEkt@aB_W]qF]uFgAkPC[QkDkBoZaAuP}@gN_AaQu@yJcAuN}AoVm@sNaAcQAYe@eGa@cFYoBuEit@_Eop@S}BoC{d@q@sKY}D[sESgBa@cC_@{AIe@wAmGqAkGuAkGgD{OmEyTcBuIoDiQw@_DaCwK_@aBYcBc@{CQoBkA{MQsCGw@AQQ{AWoB]qBe@mBoD_LiDuKcB_GoDaMSq@o@{BUs@Um@Oe@Oc@k@kBg@qAi@iAuAwCiDkH}EcK_CqEuD{HcEaJ_ByC{@mB{AwCa@y@MWMY{BgFqAqCmAgCYi@w@wAGKq@gAEEo@{@u@cA_AaAaA}@gCyBqZuW_I{GsW_Uk@i@kYsVeBwAkB}AaBsAuGcFuOiLaDeCg@a@g@a@SSSSc@e@c@m@k@y@g@u@S_@S_@Q_@S_@c@gAc@kA_A}C_CwHeGeSaC_IuBwGw@kC]gA_@cAUk@Ui@Yi@Yk@oBiDsEoIgCoEkZmi@oBiD}CkFi@_AsAcCuB{DcJiQ{Qi\\gNyVoFqJ_E_IgCmFCG}@mBo@yAWk@Uk@k@}Ai@}AqA{Dg@}Ac@}AgAyDkFeRCIsI}ZUy@kFiRgDwLaCuIgGuTg@cBwCkKkAeEc@aBg@cBs@yBw@yByBeFqCeFgC_E{@oAy@kA}@kA{@cAkG{G}JqKgR{S{MsM_U}U}JmK{EeFsEyE[[wByBoAgAi@g@uBgB{@q@{@o@uB}A{@m@}@k@eBeAeBeAqT{LsP}JwMaIcRiKkD{BsBkAy@g@{@g@sB_By@s@{@s@s@s@q@q@s@w@q@w@m@w@m@y@k@y@k@{@o@kAs@mASe@Ue@k@sAc@aAa@aAcAgCgH_ReHaRuJuX}HyTc@eAsAaEeTcj@_Uwk@qCoHqQwd@qAeD_FkMeHuQyCoHqFsNkGaLgJoLcIoKiToXiGaIcQyUmGcLyAkCgHkLiJaMcHyIwEuGkJ{OmHmNqBsDoIaQ}B}GmBmHe@uCsB}NmCmP{@kDoByDmBmDsSwb@oCqFuDyHaRc_@aFwJgDwFiK{PuGqIqC}BaQmMuQiNsCwBeT}OmIwHaEyFeEqHaNkXuFkNuEyOsDkMqByG_L}^eFmNo@oBoU_j@cGwNgOy]yMi\\qGkO_Vgk@oBsEoPy`@wBaFmDeJmJkU_K_WsMg\\kGyOuHyPuO_YeLgSaMqTeEiHyFyJgHgJoFuGsNkPwNsPsByBeFgGaKqNoOaW}GaLaFqIeAgBaAaBmFeJ{IeOmCqE{KeRaDsFwC_FkAqBo@aAoDyFwAwBeBmCuC}D_TkYoH{JcLyO{BkDo@cAo@gAg@{@q@oAsDkHq@uAoRc`@cA}BoCaFcDyGeD{Gm@mAm@oAk@sAk@wAa@iAOe@Qi@Qq@Qq@Su@Oy@Ow@Mw@K{@K}@Eo@Cq@Cq@Aq@CkA?cA@eABuHB{HHsS?gABkFDqK@aD@w@Ay@CcAEaAIgAMcAKs@Oo@Uy@]eA]eAc@}@Ug@W_@Y_@Ya@cBuBcD{DsBeC}BqCy@iAW_@{@kA{BiDcDaFuAsBuAqBkCgDi@q@oBeC{BmC}EaGwAiB{@gA{@eAq@s@o@q@u@q@w@k@{@i@}@e@_A_@}@[o@Qq@Os@Mu@IkAKiAGaDSqDQ_BIaBKwCOqAGqBMs@Eu@EyAMm@Ik@Ko@Kq@O{@Sy@Wy@Uw@[k@Um@WiAm@iAq@gAw@iAy@sBcBaAy@}BmB{BwB_CgC_KaHyG{CoE_@iIu@kOa@uPcBOAoEk@aFsBoDeB{DkBkD}AyDKsBEwBOeAGsDQoNG{BMaC[_C}AsBuDcAcD_BcImCmKkBiHuC{GeB{DgAmB}G}KqB}CeD_GoEeHmC{BkGiJyKuIMMoJkJ_@YeHyFeEoGkDsHiD}GuCsHyC_NiA_MiAcIsCmFwDcDsNaIgRqKsBaAcCiAyEwBmGmDeGkD_T}LiZgQiDoB_HaE_B{@IGEAoAs@e@YsJcGgFaDkAu@k@e@m@c@sB_BuDeDuBsBcFwFwBwCuCeEsBaDuB{DqCsFsDkJkD}KuAcF_CsKmAwHiB{NQ_CSoCg@cGw@sJSoCE_AEi@Ci@Eq@UgEGq@g@cGe@iGk@oGa@yFi@}Gc@mG}@yKa@{Fq@gJ]gEq@iJ[mDU{BqAeJw@}EaAsHo@kEcBaMwA}Ja@gCcAiG?A_AyD_C_JwAeEoCmK}AaFyCkL?C{AqFaDoLqBgH_D{KyAiFaDqLyAgFeJm[cHoWeH{VqP{l@sG_UwCuLwDiKiEcFeUcSgSqPwEkFiD{FaIsRmFwLgMsYwF_JaFoGsHwJaOmRmKmP_EiHCCsE{HuKmRgG_LuC_JU{@S}@S}@UoASgASmAg@gDe@eDe@iDS{AIw@Gs@Eq@Aw@CaACiFIgNMqSm@aIyCeXm@yJCg@a@iIc@{Ja@{Gy@gF_BwFMc@wD}LaBaGs@sCy@oEwAuIa@iC]iCq@sGyAeOu@oHs@gHq@iH{A{Oy@kIy@sHy@{G{@aJeAeJq@wGgAyHqAcJgA}Ho@_D}AaG}ByIwA}FwAcHgA}HmAgJeA{Hi@eEoEi\\_AaGIg@aBiJwDgQe@{Bg@uBg@_Bi@sAqC_HkC}FyBaFy@oB_@{@Us@Oc@Oe@Mc@Kc@k@qC{FaYq@mDUwAUwAQwAOwA_@mD{@iJkBkRy@_KmCeWcB{O[qCsAsHkG{RoFyRi@oBcBiGeFyQmBoHmBiHaHsW_HsWaBmGOk@Kg@WuAk@iDkAqImCaSOgA}BkP_Gwa@sD_SqIid@WsAwC{OoAyH}@mFsB{K[aBc@_C{BeMg@sBq@_CuBiGaAuCiD_Ls@{Ck@mCi@{Dq@gGCKIs@g@iEa@cD{@{Fy@qEiAuFoAuF_A_E_@yA_C_KuBmGmFqO}CiJg@sAaDaJeD}JqBoGsBkGmAoDCIoA_DqB_FCGcB_EaB{Di@wAcBsEkAcDi@}Au@mBQg@kA_D_AmCkAcDwA{DaAsCSk@s@uBa@wAk@eCaAsFsAgHe@wBa@aBo@aCeAgCcBcD}AuCaAyBaAcCm@qBs@{Bm@wBk@mBk@cBaAeBwA}A}AkAIEeCiAqKmDq@YgFkCYOy@c@wCwAgD{AYEeC[A?_BBg@By@JyAV_@Jk@Ro@Tc@NWLo@RcDvAsDxA{B~@aCbA}An@cA`@w@ZaA^}@ZyAb@i@PoA^_AVgB`@{@PoA\\uB\\e@FeALiBN{CPqBHoB@gB@iDGcJMkAC}NYcKU_MSsACUAoFKeGKkCEkJUkIMcACiGMmIOC?kIOwHOsDO{BQ{BUqCk@{Ag@wBs@{Aq@kBaAoAy@cAw@w@k@AAcAaAEEoAoAeBsBc@i@OS[c@eDmEk@w@eB}BwBuCwC_ESW{EuGuGyIoFmHmFiHMQ{GgJ_GcI}C}DsC}DcCiDeB_C{B_DMUs@_AGIoDuEyAuByAgCcAqBcBwDoAsDa@}AYaAy@eEq@}DK{@QaBAICi@Ei@K_BAMWiGEcAEu@Cc@Cg@WyFUgFk@wL[wHAIW{GOuDUqEAy@CyA?Q?OCiA@aA?Y@oANyCNaBR_Bz@eFPu@VgAV}@t@}Bx@oBx@_BfDkG`AgB\\q@j@eAbBwCbCmE`AaBLWvCuFxBeEp@oA|F_JjAgArAiAX]l@o@h@m@To@Vq@Ps@@[@Q?EAYG}@I_@Sw@Sg@Yg@iBiB[[[YsCmC{@w@" }, "start_location" : { "lat" : 34.072538, "lng" : 49.7755983 }, "travel_mode" : "DRIVING" }, { "distance" : { "text" : "127 km", "value" : 127131 }, "duration" : { "text" : "1 hour 15 mins", "value" : 4503 }, "end_location" : { "lat" : 35.6126999, "lng" : 51.3658516 }, "html_instructions" : "Keep \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e at the fork and merge onto \u003cb\u003ePersian Gulf Hwy\u003c/b\u003e/\u003cb\u003eRoute 7\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003ePartial toll road\u003c/div\u003e", "maneuver" : "fork-left", "polyline" : { "points" : "cbtrEugsuHyAkAwAqAkJwIy@u@w@u@WSUMWMWISGUEOAW?U@WDWJUJSJSR_@^QXOXGXI`@G\\Ed@Cd@Cj@EnEG~BGt@Kr@i@pBk@~AyFhJu@xA}ElGkBlCqDhEcCpCqCvC{B~BkCfCyBfB}BnB{B`BgCjBkA~@yBrAqEtCuGlD}HdEqDfB_D|AuBfAkLlFwJhEwHxCqAh@kIrCmNvEcHrBy@XeDdAcDbAyMfEcAZy@Tw@VkOzEqInCE@u@R}E`ByJnCuFrAaB`@gE`AcATaAP{AVyATqDh@_BRI@aBRiFj@_BP}ALiBNgBLeCN}BH_CH_ABu@@oBB}ZFcFAg@?cDBaFBoTHkBBuCF_GNuFTM?M@M@M?M@M@M?M@M@M?M@M@M?M@M?M@M@M?M@M@M?M@M@M?M@M@M?M@O@M?M@M@M?M@M@M?M@M?M@M@M@M@MBM@MBM@M@MBM@M@MBM@MBM@M@MBM@MBM@M@MBM@M@KBM@MBM@M@MBM@M@MBM@MBM@M@MBM@MBMBMBKBM@MBMBMBMBM@MBMBKBMBMBM@MBMBMBMBM@KB{AHyXxEcKzBs@R_@JQFsElAmBf@__@pKy]jK_KrBsO|CoPlCmRbCo@FqKfAmO|@qIb@oELcGNiFFa@@wDBoD@mFAw@?s@AmAAaAC_BAw@?}CIuCGwGUyGUoGU{DMgHOgLKeE@mDByCDeCDeIRsCJyETgBJeEVyCTiCTuBPcCVkGp@}ARqFv@c@Fc@F}JrAmBVuGt@iLbAgBL{@DuCP_ETuFViBDy@BoCDaEF}CBkD@_DAyA?cDGoFK_DGwCKeCM{BM{DS}DY{CW_BOsD_@w@KsBUu@KqBWkC]{B]}AUeCa@}A]m@MeS_EmXsFgQwBgGaAkG_@wZiBgIm@e@Es[s@{MKyA@_PH}T\\{AJc^GqLOcQQkU{@iIm@aYuCwJeAaC_@_De@wa@oG}F{@cAMad@sGyEq@mC[E?kOyAoIk@{Ik@kJg@aGKsIQiHMmE?Y?kKDwDBeHJwCJ_KXyKh@uOfAoNnAuCXcf@tHar@nLmJ`BmFr@iQ~B}Dn@qK~@qPxA{Lt@iG`@I?cVl@eIPaB@}GHmRCePQ{@C{DIkFKg@CiZ}A{ZoCcYiDuSaDgUoD_@KgUeFiSeH{h@aRqG}Ba`@{Nqh@aSeJ}D_h@wTcDeBwK{FkBaAe@WqAq@qJ_FyBuAaAm@c`@mVaBkAyQqMoQ}MmAiA{JmIwJ}IyHoGgJwJsCmCkQuQoHqIkZa^uBkCmY_c@wJ_OoOgYeZij@oK{SyK_WmWyl@w@gBiCwDaH_OyJeTKS{@eC_@w@oMwXwA}CyEsJkA_CQ_@kAeBwDyGkAgB}DeGiEcGgAiAaAyAw^w_@{GcFyHoFgHkFsBiAwBmA_C}@yQkIgKsDyJsCgD_AoSmEoUoEiNmCkL}B}LyCgBc@{J_CoGmB_DaAgG{BwD_Bm@UeLmFeFoCsB}A}AuAkBmAqDeCuByAcBmAuC_C{DaD{AuA][kAaAqDoDmDsDeBiBeCyCmAuAuAcBqCsD}AuB{BaDiBsCiDsFsBcDgAwBgEyHwAuCuA_DgB{D_AsBcAeC_@gAwB}Fa@kAu@{BoA_EkAyD_AeDiBmHeAmEo@uCqAmGi@_DeAwGuA_JYaCm@uE[iDc@sEc@cFm@oJ_@sHCa@_@gL]mM]sMU}IWmJMkF]}IWsEg@cIOgBI_Ak@oGw@sHc@kDo@uEaAuGk@mDy@oEa@oBa@yBc@wBuB{IsBcIwAsEo@uBeEiM}@eCyCoHgBgEyAgDgAyByAyCeBeDmBoDsCkFgBgDoBsDgBaD_BwC_AaBqD}G}BoEyAwCsD{HeAcCcB_EeAsCu@oBcCcH}@iC_BkFsA{EgA{DgAuEeBqHYwAWuA_@kBq@qDy@gFi@eDq@aFy@oHs@oG_@iEo@_Jq@aJc@qGGu@{@mKy@}Ik@mEs@uF_A}Fm@aEi@{Cs@mDoAiG_BaHqAcFm@aCcB}FuDiLuA_EaBiEsAiDqLsVoK{QmEqGoBuCgLyNsEaFwGwGYWaGiFcFaEaGsEkFyBwEqC}D}ByC{AcD}AoFeCkGkCmGyBkHaCwA_@cD{@oFqAeJmBoJuByFsAqAYmIeCmH_C}HuCsHwCSIeJ}DoJuEoDiBgJwFo@a@oHwEwMaJeJaGo@_@sGyDsJgFyFoCaKmEcCeBuD{Ay@WuHkCyJyCqFuAiLeCoE}@eHgAgHaAyGw@eI_AoIy@iEs@yEk@yEy@kKyBkLgCiMsDyGoBkE}AsCkA{HyCwHeDoFoCkC{AkCoAoGgDsG_EuNmImDuBcHiEaIuEmIyEgR}K_HqDiG{C{JmEuIgD_FeBoC}@eCs@yEyAuEgBsEmA_FgAuCm@}IaB_JqAoGy@qGs@sFg@mIk@oIa@cL_@qAEmKM]?kIEgMIyA?G?}@E_ACyGKk@AeYuAqQuA_BSiBWiCYgJeAoNqBoEq@{Dy@cEw@eKwBeRkEsRyD_K{A}JqAwQuAaLw@kJa@c@A[AWA{@@iA?sG[sCAaUDeFVeBH{VbAqGZuG\\iOp@mDLoDHeJH_EAcKWeKe@eIq@eIy@wCa@{Ce@sHoAqFiAmCk@aDy@_@K{@W[MmBe@c@MeEgAsC_AmFqBkFsBeFiCmFqCiAi@aHaEoCaBoCeBkCkBwCkBq@g@_BeAqCsBqDyCuB_BuBeBmCoCuAuAaC_CiCiC{CoDwBcC}AkB{BqCaByBaAsA}BeDwBeD}A_Co@iAaAeBc@o@a@o@{@yAa@q@o@kAaCaEmBsDkCwE}@}A_D}FeBuC}@{AgCyDyGgHuGmJ_N}M_FmEaJoHkAaAoLgIeCaBgRgMyHwEyCyBqC}B_G{EqFqFiDaD}CqDmAoAeEkFcEmFoJgNyCcFsHmNeCeF}BeFeFeMM]oEaNaBsFyAsFoBwHcBwHiB{ICSyAoI}BiNmB{KKm@CM{@gESgA{AyGwDaOiEwNK]k@iBgB}EoBgFSi@kAaDUe@CECESi@KUcAeC{BoFm@uAaBmDIScCgF_@u@_D{FkCoEcBiCsEoGm@{@wJkNkHmKiEyGmDeGKScCsEiBqDQ_@]u@[q@Sc@sAwCgAkCqB}EmDiJkDgKaEcOuD}N}@qD}GwWqF}Ss@mCaAmDyCkKgBsFeCqHgD}IO][w@sBcFk@sAwCuGkDsGeBmDwCcFeByC{@{AmDiFuGiJgCaDwEcGaEoEkAuA_A_AiAiAkAkAqAoAmAkAcDyC{EaEmAaA{AkAeBqAuAeAiD_CSOg@]q@e@aAk@q@c@{AaAqCeBeB_AcB}@aCoAcAg@GCy@c@eCkAaBu@qAk@iBu@u@[y@[eBq@uAi@{Ag@oDmAoFiBo@SeEuA_Bi@iBo@eFcBwBs@{Bu@aCy@gDgA{Bq@y@UuEoAmEeAwCo@gDm@wDq@sDi@}@Mu@ImBUaBSuAMqDYqAKqAIsAIwAGgBG}AGcCGiBCmBEyBGuBIaAEu@E}AIwBOgAIoCSiCQ{BM}CM}AEu@C{@AyACuAAiA?mBAuA@eB@sCFqABgBFqADsAHmBJyBNsAJmCV{ANw@Jy@HUB_ALg@H{BZwB\\eBZcBZaB\\}E~@cGjAwBb@wCr@]HuBh@eD`AkA^iAZoBp@aBl@_@NkAb@}@^_EfBmAr@mB`AaCjAcD`BqBbAu@^WJc@RaClAMHUL" }, "start_location" : { "lat" : 34.6782574, "lng" : 50.8941868 }, "travel_mode" : "DRIVING" }, { "distance" : { "text" : "2.2 km", "value" : 2158 }, "duration" : { "text" : "2 mins", "value" : 110 }, "end_location" : { "lat" : 35.6312923, "lng" : 51.3595602 }, "html_instructions" : "Keep \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e to continue on \u003cb\u003eKazemi Expy\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003ePass by the gas station (on the left in 1.3 km)\u003c/div\u003e", "maneuver" : "keep-left", "polyline" : { "points" : "krjxEqkoxHcExBmCtAmBdAaAb@aAb@uAt@g@R}@\\m@Tq@Ru@TsAXmAVsATi@FuARmALu@J{ALeFd@iDZeDVeALs@H]Dm@HYDc@He@Hc@JeDr@{Dz@gDt@cCh@u@`@qQ|D" }, "start_location" : { "lat" : 35.6126999, "lng" : 51.3658516 }, "travel_mode" : "DRIVING" }, { "distance" : { "text" : "0.4 km", "value" : 419 }, "duration" : { "text" : "1 min", "value" : 30 }, "end_location" : { "lat" : 35.6350103, "lng" : 51.3589043 }, "html_instructions" : "Slight \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e at سرای عالی", "maneuver" : "turn-slight-right", "polyline" : { "points" : "qfnxEgdnxHw@?yBV]C]HmB\\m@HMBK@cCVW@wBLo@N" }, "start_location" : { "lat" : 35.6312923, "lng" : 51.3595602 }, "travel_mode" : "DRIVING" }, { "distance" : { "text" : "0.4 km", "value" : 380 }, "duration" : { "text" : "1 min", "value" : 32 }, "end_location" : { "lat" : 35.6381833, "lng" : 51.3597697 }, "html_instructions" : "Take the ramp to \u003cb\u003eCheraghi Expy\u003c/b\u003e", "polyline" : { "points" : "y}nxEc`nxHUBYBQ@Q?U@UC]EWG_@Me@Q_@O]KYCY?c@BoAJ]COEQC][Y_@OSOY" }, "start_location" : { "lat" : 35.6350103, "lng" : 51.3589043 }, "travel_mode" : "DRIVING" }, { "distance" : { "text" : "3.1 km", "value" : 3057 }, "duration" : { "text" : "4 mins", "value" : 216 }, "end_location" : { "lat" : 35.6564958, "lng" : 51.3824297 }, "html_instructions" : "Keep \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e and merge onto \u003cb\u003eCheraghi Expy\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003ePass by فروشگاه Reform (on the right in 550 m)\u003c/div\u003e", "maneuver" : "keep-left", "polyline" : { "points" : "sqoxEqenxH]m@OYEKW[K]s@iBkAaDu@aBsAqDi@mA_@w@m@uASg@EGwA}BwCqDwAgBS]{@kAYe@[e@aDwDAAgAwAcAiAmAaA{@o@oAs@i@UkBu@e@OqD{@cDs@{C}@uAa@}CkA_C_BaCwBk@e@aAcAw@kAcBuCyAmDOa@oBgJIc@E_@o@uJIyAK{@WkAOg@O_@Wg@]c@UYg@[YSYS}@c@y@OmAS" }, "start_location" : { "lat" : 35.6381833, "lng" : 51.3597697 }, "travel_mode" : "DRIVING" }, { "distance" : { "text" : "1.3 km", "value" : 1335 }, "duration" : { "text" : "2 mins", "value" : 102 }, "end_location" : { "lat" : 35.6684825, "lng" : 51.3816942 }, "html_instructions" : "Merge onto \u003cb\u003eNavvab Expy\u003c/b\u003e", "maneuver" : "merge", "polyline" : { "points" : "cdsxEesrxHSA_A@mA@G?sBF{CFq@BaDD_@@kFNe@@}AF}_@dAcABu@DmBFM?i@B" }, "start_location" : { "lat" : 35.6564958, "lng" : 51.3824297 }, "travel_mode" : "DRIVING" }, { "distance" : { "text" : "0.2 km", "value" : 241 }, "duration" : { "text" : "1 min", "value" : 30 }, "end_location" : { "lat" : 35.6706278, "lng" : 51.381785 }, "html_instructions" : "Slight \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e", "maneuver" : "turn-slight-right", "polyline" : { "points" : "_ouxEqnrxHOMWCSEWCs@Cw@AaADuBDu@B" }, "start_location" : { "lat" : 35.6684825, "lng" : 51.3816942 }, "travel_mode" : "DRIVING" }, { "distance" : { "text" : "0.9 km", "value" : 912 }, "duration" : { "text" : "2 mins", "value" : 149 }, "end_location" : { "lat" : 35.6787571, "lng" : 51.3808369 }, "html_instructions" : "Continue straight", "maneuver" : "straight", "polyline" : { "points" : "m|uxEcorxHoAB}ADGBM@MBwJ`A]FiIx@}BJk@DkDP}GTWE[O" }, "start_location" : { "lat" : 35.6706278, "lng" : 51.381785 }, "travel_mode" : "DRIVING" }, { "distance" : { "text" : "31 m", "value" : 31 }, "duration" : { "text" : "1 min", "value" : 11 }, "end_location" : { "lat" : 35.6787368, "lng" : 51.3811778 }, "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e at Madar Restaurant onto \u003cb\u003eMahboub Mojaz St\u003c/b\u003e", "maneuver" : "turn-right", "polyline" : { "points" : "gowxEgirxHBcA" }, "start_location" : { "lat" : 35.6787571, "lng" : 51.3808369 }, "travel_mode" : "DRIVING" }, { "distance" : { "text" : "0.4 km", "value" : 350 }, "duration" : { "text" : "1 min", "value" : 82 }, "end_location" : { "lat" : 35.6818692, "lng" : 51.3808748 }, "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e at مؤسسه فرهنگی هنری پیشرو Pishro Institute onto \u003cb\u003eS Khoshyaran\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003ePass by Residential pear (on the left)\u003c/div\u003e", "maneuver" : "turn-left", "polyline" : { "points" : "cowxEkkrxHi@B{@HcADqA@uJf@" }, "start_location" : { "lat" : 35.6787368, "lng" : 51.3811778 }, "travel_mode" : "DRIVING" }, { "distance" : { "text" : "0.2 km", "value" : 159 }, "duration" : { "text" : "1 min", "value" : 37 }, "end_location" : { "lat" : 35.6820234, "lng" : 51.3826158 }, "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e at Enqelab Cultural House Parking onto \u003cb\u003eKomeyl St\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003ePass by دفتر پیشخوان و خدمات سیم کارت برادران ملکی 72161796 (on the right)\u003c/div\u003e", "maneuver" : "turn-right", "polyline" : { "points" : "ubxxEmirxHI_@G{BAw@Ag@GaB" }, "start_location" : { "lat" : 35.6818692, "lng" : 51.3808748 }, "travel_mode" : "DRIVING" }, { "distance" : { "text" : "0.2 km", "value" : 230 }, "duration" : { "text" : "1 min", "value" : 58 }, "end_location" : { "lat" : 35.6839107, "lng" : 51.3826573 }, "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e at Hairdressers Glara toward \u003cb\u003eKashan St\u003c/b\u003e", "maneuver" : "turn-left", "polyline" : { "points" : "scxxEktrxHC@kDLgETAm@" }, "start_location" : { "lat" : 35.6820234, "lng" : 51.3826158 }, "travel_mode" : "DRIVING" }, { "distance" : { "text" : "56 m", "value" : 56 }, "duration" : { "text" : "1 min", "value" : 10 }, "end_location" : { "lat" : 35.68411990000001, "lng" : 51.383132 }, "html_instructions" : "Slight \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e at دبیرستان نمونه دولتی دخترانه دوره اول شایسته", "maneuver" : "turn-slight-left", "polyline" : { "points" : "moxxEstrxHUKKIEKCGAIAID_@" }, "start_location" : { "lat" : 35.6839107, "lng" : 51.3826573 }, "travel_mode" : "DRIVING" }, { "distance" : { "text" : "0.3 km", "value" : 282 }, "duration" : { "text" : "1 min", "value" : 32 }, "end_location" : { "lat" : 35.6830855, "lng" : 51.3859814 }, "html_instructions" : "Continue straight onto \u003cb\u003eKashan St\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003ePass by کاشان (on the right)\u003c/div\u003e", "maneuver" : "straight", "polyline" : { "points" : "wpxxEqwrxHjBoH`BiG" }, "start_location" : { "lat" : 35.68411990000001, "lng" : 51.383132 }, "travel_mode" : "DRIVING" }, { "distance" : { "text" : "62 m", "value" : 62 }, "duration" : { "text" : "1 min", "value" : 25 }, "end_location" : { "lat" : 35.6825616, "lng" : 51.38573599999999 }, "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003eDestination will be on the right\u003c/div\u003e", "maneuver" : "turn-right", "polyline" : { "points" : "ijxxEkisxHvAf@PF" }, "start_location" : { "lat" : 35.6830855, "lng" : 51.3859814 }, "travel_mode" : "DRIVING" } ], "traffic_speed_entry" : [], "via_waypoint" : [] } ], "overview_polyline" : { "points" : "i`boEobmnHeS}j@wHkHgBlIa`@lYqToEyn@ijAiG_Od@gFjaByyA|yCqmCfYeQrEyAIaNk\\aeFqZ}aFmUaoD_Iyg@qb@eaC_]{lAsq@owAelB}dBin@ui@_b@umAkvBg{Dio@_yBkUex@o[se@}qBisBqgBcgAkd@_bAuzA{}DqVwn@id@uu@uwAcqBc^sm@aRch@mLqk@ga@qy@uj@odA_q@gk@ii@ge@sb@cbAk\\qeAko@a|A_wA_jDuk@{vAcq@clAymAk}Aoz@}vAm}Aa_Cot@a|AuByk@Pqt@kCwNye@yp@wg@wh@wk@iEy]mPyVoS_i@sGw^eGqU{Hsi@_EuY{{@eWab@aYiY{Zo[eSej@sCcWkIqKsi@_ZaxAey@yYyQs`@uc@gRyd@mKkl@iDkd@aPiuB}OugA_Taw@ke@wbBok@gsBoI_Yo[gZ_Z}WkNoZoc@{z@yfAkcBwLir@wHwdB_Fwb@{IwZgMkdAoNauA}SyfAaSevAe]qfAwMgz@wKmgAkR{t@sf@cjBgM{{@wd@ulCwR{u@yZ}~Amq@ulBa[meAkOu_@{L{Uee@eS}MT{f@pReR|Did@Ti_CmEy]sHgJwHk_AioAy]_f@eSy_@aGyn@sCkeApGqYvSs_@d\\ui@_EoJ_ZgXoE_C{D~AiAdGa@xLeKtSsc@~f@mj@z]a}@|_@mv@hVwsAv]ymArDkcAbB}ZbDco@fLqvBzh@mqAzI}hAeB}x@Tqh@`EgrAdL}nAmD_YyD_q@_Ns}@cIqbB}@etAeBes@iHiaBaVqrAeGkiAlDoxCtc@_xArHgxAgC}_BkSmtAyb@s{CuoAekAyt@swA_qA_bA_qA}bAmiBmaAywBcc@a|@{O{Tos@eq@wcAuc@glBua@kn@eZc]oWm]w_@i]kk@ib@cuAuJa|@{DwqA_Gmw@uLgp@{Y}z@iYsi@g[_o@aSko@wUooBuLux@eWcz@_c@wv@m\\k_@gt@ce@eyBkq@kkAsq@gt@y^ckAaWuoAiUuv@u[cvAcy@k}@u^__AmQs|BgHicA_Mcx@uPwv@{Hq^cAi~AdFcgAyDib@wIyk@}Taa@yVg|@o_Aih@}|@of@ai@c^{Wg_Ayt@yo@odA}\\yjAiLup@aWk{@w_@uw@e{@mxAebAafD}\\on@ya@kg@_o@if@ml@kWmiAy\\mgBcL{o@~Bcw@nOurA|k@sg@tFaz@~OsOe@eGy@kDeHw]gm@}NuKm_@cOmNg\\{CgVuIiEmSZm{@tAkx@zEsSu@S}HyJG`AmKjEyE" }, "summary" : "Route 56 and Persian Gulf Hwy/Route 7", "warnings" : [], "waypoint_order" : [] } ], "status" : "OK" } ';
$arrayMessage = json_decode($data);

foreach ($arrayMessage->geocoded_waypoints as $item) {
    echo $item->geocoder_status;
}
?>
```

Comment: The warning says it all. You're treating it as an object when it's not. It could be an array. `echo $item['geocoder_status']`

Comment: `json_decode` returns `null` because it failed to decode `$data` so in your `foreach` you failed to access to the `geocoded_waypoints`property

Comment: @hungrykoala, nope. Read the docs please.

Comment: There is a syntax error in the JSON https://3v4l.org/L2jvL

Comment: hungrykoala, that's only the case if you pass true as a 2nd argument http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Your json string is not valid you can see error json decode online editor.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$data` contains malformed JSON string thus `json_decode` does not return correct object. Before iterating over it you can check whether your string was parsed correctly:

```
if (json_last_error()) {
    die(json_last_error_msg());
}
```

Your script will begin to work as soon as you fix your JSON string. You can play with `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` too.

Ps. you can't just copy a JSON output out of a debugger and expect this to work as this is how you have done in the first place I expect.